# How to prove that:$ BC^2= 3CM^2 + AC^2 $from this triangle problem?

Tags: triangles

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, angle $\angle A$ is larger than angle $\angle B$.

We choose points $M$ and  $N$ at $AB$ such that $AM=MN=NB$.

How to prove that: $BC^2= 3CM^2 + AC^2$?

Which theorem(s) should I use to prove this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use section formula as M and N trisect AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points $A,M,N$ and $B$ are equally spaced on $(AB)$.
Set a coordinate system with origin at $A$ and $(AB)$ as first
axis.

Then the coordinates of $A,M,N$ and $B$ will be :

$$
A(0,0) \ M(t,0) \ N(2t,0) \ B(3t,0)
$$

for some constant $t$. Now, if we denote by 
$(x,y)$ the coordinates of $C$, one has

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
BC^2 &=& (x-3t)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2-6xt+9t^2 \\
3CM^2 &=& 3((x-t)^2+y^2)=3x^2+3y^2-6xt+3t^2 \\
AC^2 &=& (x-0)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2 \\
\end{array}
$$

and hence

$$
BC^2-(3CM^2+AC^2)=-3x^2-3y^2+6t^2
$$

so your equality holds iff $x^2+y^2=2t^2$. You probably forgot
a condition on $C$

Comment: the only condition from this problem is angle A is larger than angle B. How can we use this condition to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: @akusaja My formula shows that your problem is false as stated now. Take for example $x=0,y=1$ and $t=1$. Then there is a right angle at $A$, so $\hat{A}$ is indeed larger than $\hat{B}$